Write a Jenkins pipeline to build a project and adding file into the build for a second repository
I’m writing a Jenkins declarative pipeline with this situation.
I build a maven project and, after the build, i should add some file in a specific directory of the project from a second repository.
This is necessary for me to use a repository for file like templates and other thing different from project file. In this mode i can modify templates without modify the maven project.
How can i implement this in Jenkins?
I write the First part, build the project without adding templates file
